# Git repo organization for cloud deployment

Tags: git, azure, web

I'm having trouble figuring out the best git repository organization for a web app that is going to be hosted on Azure.

For example, I want all of my code to be monorepo, but I need to have separate sections of code that I can push to the individual Azure services eg: Web App and API App as if I push the entire project to an API app, it will not understand how to execute just the API.

Is best practice for cloud deployment to have submodules or to have individual projects/repos for each section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have a single git repository that deploys multiple projects to different targets in Azure.  Full details are [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments), but essentially you specify an appSetting named **PROJECT** with a value that points to the project file that should be deployed to the desired target.